# Laravel - Get collection from multiple relationships

Tags: laravel

I apologize if this isn't a great question but I'm still getting used to eloquent relationships.

On my website users can be moderators of subchans (sub channels). Subchans have modmail that all moderators of that subchan can see.

So I have a user model, and in this user model I have a relationship to the Moderator model:

```
public function modOf()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Moderator::class, 'user_id', 'id')->where('activated', 1);
}
```

then in the moderator model, I have a relationship that points to the subchan model:

```
public function subchan()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Subchan::class, 'subchan_id');
}
```

then in the subchan model, I have a relationship that returns all the Modmail for that subchannel:

```
public function modMail()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\ModMail::class, 'subchan_id');
}
```

So now I want to create a page where I can foreach and paginate all the modmail that the Auth user has.

How do I pass only the modmail from the controller into the view?

Comment: $user->load('modOf.subchan.modMail');

Comment: @AnuratChapanond wouldn't this load all of the previous relationship data as well? What if I just want the modmail?

Comment: yes, you may be able to pass through with hasManyThrough()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do this the normal way. I thought there would be an eloquent relationship way to do it but I guess not. Here is my solution:

```
    $modOfSubchanIDs = Auth::user()->modOf->pluck('id')->toArray();
    
    $modMails = ModMail::whereIn('subchan_id', $modOfSubchanIDs)->paginate(25);
```